# Page break not working with table

Tags: html, css

I have tried the code below for page break after particular row of the table while printing. It didn't break the page. All rows appeared on the same page while printing.

```css
.page-break {
  page-break-after: always;
}
```

```html
<tr class="page-break">
  <td>--</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Could you explain what your expected outcome is?

Comment: I have 6 rows in table.When we print that table, table should be divided into two pages (each page -3 rows) .For that i have added  page-break class for 3rd row .

Comment: You should expand the example table so it has several rows, and add the desired output in your question body.

Comment: "I have 6 rows in table" Where are these 6 rows in your example? Try to make your question as detailed as possible, including your current code, wanted result etc will result in more input by the users.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you can use it on an `<tr>` (not a block level element)

"Applies to block-level elements in the normal flow of the root element. User agents may also apply it to other elements like table-row elements."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the @media print. That media query is specific for when you're setting something to print.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp

**ANSWER UPDATE**:

After some searching, @anderssonola is correct about not being able to use it with `<tr>`. So, you will have a couple options depending on how you've set up your page. The ones off the top of my head are below:

***Option 1 = use `<div>` to break them apart.***

For that you could do something like:

```css
@media print {
    div.page-break {page-break-after: always;}
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>Page One</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <div class="page-break">
    <tr>
      <td>Page Two</td>
    </tr>
  </div>
</table>
```

***Option 2 = use `<table>` to break them apart.***

```css
@media print {
    .page-break {page-break-after: always;}
}
```

```html
<table class="page-break">
    <tr>
      <td>Page One</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="page-break">
    <tr>
      <td>Page Two</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

***Option 3 = use an HTML5 element to break them apart.***

```css
@media print {
    section {page-break-after: always;}
}
```

```html
<section>
Page One
</section>
<section>
Page Two
</section>
```

Comment: I have tried and it is also not working.. @media print {
         tr.page-break {page-break-after: always;}
   }